# Apply NumPy repeat only on elements that are contained in a secondary list

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to repeat certain elements within a list `n`-times and so far I've come to this solution:

```
                _base = ["a", "z", "c", "c", "e"]
                for bump_element in ["a", "b", "c"]:
                    _base = np.repeat(
                        np.array(_base),
                        np.where(np.array(_base) == bump_element, 2, 1)
                    )
```

So far this works, `_base` will be `['a' 'a' 'z' 'c' 'c' 'c' 'c' 'e']`. However, I'm trying to make it faster by removing the for loop so that within a single `repeat` I can catch all elements. Something like:

```
                    _base = np.repeat(
                        np.array(_base),
                        np.where(np.array(_base) in ["a", "b", "c"], 2, 1)
                    )
```

But that won't work since it will throw `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

Is there an easy way to make that `where` clause to check every item in the list against the one which contains the elements to be repeated?

Comment: what's the expected result? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the for loop over the possible values in 'bump_element', you can use  [numpy isin](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html).

```
_base = np.array(["a", "z", "c", "c", "e"])
bump = np.array(["a", "b", "c"])
np.repeat(_base, np.where(np.isin(_base, bump), 2, 1))
```